# How can I get a refund when I am in a country and I bought something that is based in other country?

Tags: united-states, online-shopping

I hope this is a good place to ask about this, if it is not please let me know in a comment and I will delete the question.

I have bought a downloadable game in a website which its based in a country different than mine.
I feel the game was not properly advertised and it is faulty. I won't be able to play the game.

If the company was in my same country I know where I could go to get help but, since the company is based in United States and I am not from there I am not sure how could I work it out to get a refund.

I have tried to contact the Company but they don't have a way I could send them feedback. They just have a technical issues support.

Again I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask this, and thanks for your time!

Comment: What was the other country? Did you purchase the game using a credit card?

Comment: Yes I used a credit card.

Comment: @JohnBensin I forgot to say I leave in Argentina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you take this to your credit card issuer. I don't know what the Argentinian laws are on the matter, but in all the places I do know what the laws are - they're the same.

You dispute the charge with your credit card issuer claiming that the product is not as advertised. The issuer will contact the merchant account provider of the company you bought from and transmit your complaint to them. The company will have to respond, and in the end **your** credit card issuer will have to decide whether they agree that your claim is valid, or not. If they side with you, they issue a charge back and refund your money (the merchant account provider for that company will charge their account).

Since you did in fact receive a product, you'll have to show why you think it is not as advertised, so get as much proofs as you can - screenshots, descriptions, ads that you relied upon, etc.

This is called "charge-back" process and is a pretty standard and similar procedure with both Visa and Mastercard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your answer! I didn't think I could do that. Of course with Online content proving I am right can be hard to do. But thanks for your advice!